# 2 Fingerprint scanner using 1 arduino

Tags: arduino-mega

I have problem in using 2 fingerprint scanner in arduino mega, every time I need to register I need to go and register my fingerprint on each fingerprint module,

> what i am planning to do is when I registered on 1 fingerprint scanner
>   then the other fingerprint module automatically registered the
>   fingerprint and vise versa.

Can anyone help me with my project thanks. btw my project was already working but I have problems in registration of bio-metrics.

here is my code in verifying the registered fingerprint

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
int door1 = 8;
int door2 = 11;
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger1 = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&Serial2);
//fplabas
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger2 = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&Serial3);
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);

pinMode(door2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(door1, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(Buzzer, OUTPUT);
//
  digitalWrite(door2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(door1, HIGH);


 finger1.begin(57600);
  finger2.begin(57600);
    if (finger1.verifyPassword() || finger2.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensors!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find any fingerprint sensors :(");
    while (1) { delay(1); }
  }

  finger1.getTemplateCount();
  finger2.getTemplateCount();

  Serial.print("Fingerprint Sensor1 contains "); Serial.print(finger1.templateCount); Serial.println(" templates");
  Serial.print("Fingerprint Sensor2 contains "); Serial.print(finger2.templateCount); Serial.println(" templates");
  Serial.println("Waiting for valid finger...");
}



void loop () {
  getFingerprintdoor2();
  delay(50);           
  //Fingerprint Sensor Labas
  getFingerprintdoor1();
  delay(50);
}

uint8_t getFingerprintdoor2() {
  uint8_t p = finger1.getImage();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      //Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
     // Serial.println("No finger detected");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
    //  Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      //Serial.println("Imaging error");
      return p;
    default:
      //Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }
  // OK success!

  p = finger1.image2Tz();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      //Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      //Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
     // Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
     // Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
     // Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      //Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  p = finger1.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Found a print match!");
    digitalWrite(door2, LOW); 
//    sendsms(textForSMS + " Noah", f1001);
//    Serial.println(textForSMS);
//    Serial.println("message sent.");  
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(door2, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
   // Serial.print(finger1.fingerID); 
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    //Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND) {
//    Serial.println("Did not find a match");
//    digitalWrite(Buzzer,LOW);
//    delay(1000);
//    digitalWrite(Buzzer,HIGH);
    return p;
  } else {
    //Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   

  return finger1.fingerID;
}


uint8_t getFingerprintdoor1() {
  uint8_t p = finger2.getImage();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      //Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
     // Serial.println("No finger detected");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
    //  Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      //Serial.println("Imaging error");
      return p;
    default:
      //Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger2.image2Tz();
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      //Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      //Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
     // Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
     // Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
     // Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      //Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  p = finger2.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Found a print match!");

    digitalWrite(door1, LOW); 

   delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(door1, HIGH);

  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    //Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_NOTFOUND) {

    return p;
  } else {
    //Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   

  // found a match!
  return finger2.fingerID;
}
```

And here is the problem code where I need to register on both Fingerprint scanner:

```
#include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&Serial2);

Adafruit_Fingerprint finger2 = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&Serial3);

uint8_t id;

void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("\n\nAdafruit Fingerprint sensor enrollment");

  // set the data rate for the sensor serial port
  finger.begin(57600);

  if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
    Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
    while (1) { delay(1); }
  }
}

uint8_t readnumber(void) {
  uint8_t num = 0;

  while (num == 0) {
    while (! Serial.available());
    num = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  return num;
}

void loop()                    
{
  Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
  Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger as...");


 if (Serial.available()>0)
   switch(Serial.read())
  {
    case 'A':

        id = readnumber();
        if (id == 0) {
           return;
        }
        Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
        Serial.println(id);

        while (!  getFingerprintEnroll1() );

      break;

       case 'B':

        id = readnumber();
        if (id == 0) {
           return;
        }
        Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
        Serial.println(id);

        while (!  getFingerprintEnroll2() );

      break;

}

}

uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll1() {

  int p = -1;
  Serial.print("Waiting for valid finger to enroll as #"); Serial.println(id);
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz(1);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  Serial.println("Remove finger");
  delay(2000);
  p = 0;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER) {
    p = finger.getImage();
  }
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = -1;
  Serial.println("Place same finger again");
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.print(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger.image2Tz(2);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  Serial.print("Creating model for #");  Serial.println(id);

  p = finger.createModel();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Prints matched!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH) {
    Serial.println("Fingerprints did not match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   

  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = finger.storeModel(id);
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Stored!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION) {
    Serial.println("Could not store in that location");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR) {
    Serial.println("Error writing to flash");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
}

uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll2() {

  int p = -1;
  Serial.print("Waiting for valid finger to enroll as #"); Serial.println(id);
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger2.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.println(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger2.image2Tz(1);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  Serial.println("Remove finger");
  delay(2000);
  p = 0;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER) {
    p = finger2.getImage();
  }
  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = -1;
  Serial.println("Place same finger again");
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger2.getImage();
    switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image taken");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
      Serial.print(".");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
      Serial.println("Imaging error");
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      break;
    }
  }

  // OK success!

  p = finger2.image2Tz(2);
  switch (p) {
    case FINGERPRINT_OK:
      Serial.println("Image converted");
      break;
    case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
      Serial.println("Image too messy");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
      Serial.println("Communication error");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
      Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
      return p;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown error");
      return p;
  }

  // OK converted!
  Serial.print("Creating model for #");  Serial.println(id);

  p = finger2.createModel();
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Prints matched!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH) {
    Serial.println("Fingerprints did not match");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   

  Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
  p = finger2.storeModel(id);
  if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    Serial.println("Stored!");
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
    Serial.println("Communication error");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION) {
    Serial.println("Could not store in that location");
    return p;
  } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR) {
    Serial.println("Error writing to flash");
    return p;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Unknown error");
    return p;
  }   
}
```

Please help I am stuck in this situation..

Comment: did you do that and works properly?

Answer (score 1):

The library, that you are using, doesn't seem to support exporting or importing fingerprints. Though if you look into the [user manual](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/ZFM+user+manualV15.pdf) of the fingerprint sensor at the Adafruit site, there are two commands mentioned, that seem to do what you need:

> 6.2.2 Upload image:  UpImage
>
> Description: to  upload  the  image  in Img_Buffer  to  upper  computer.  Refer  to  1.1.1  for  more  about image buffer.
>
> 6.2.3 Download the image: DownImage
>
> Description: to download image from upper computer to Img_Buffer. Refer to 1.1.1 for more about the image buffer.

These commands can be used to read or write the image buffer, where an image is stored, when it was taken by the sensor (this is only about the image data, not about the recognition or enrolling; that has to be done after loading the image to the buffer). I could not find corresponding functions in the library, so I guess it doesn't support this. So, to get what you need, you need to stop using the library and handle the things yourself (or - maybe better - extend the library to incorporate that feature).

The manual has no good documentation about these functions and the datasheet, that Adafruit has, is in Chinese, so I couldn't read it. You will need to try it out and see, what you get, when issuing the mentioned commands (unless you can read Chinese and there is more useful information in that datasheet).

I guess after requesting the upload of the current image, the module will send data packets in the configured package size, until it has transferred the whole image (Note, that it will only send 4 bits for every pixel over UART, meaning 16-greyscale image). After than you could request the download on the other module. After the acknowledgement packet, I guess you need to send the image data in the same format, as you received it from the first module, in packets with the configured packet size.

When configured to the same packet size, you could request upload and download at the same time for each module and simply let the packets pass through. After transferring the image, you can start the recognition on both modules.

Comment: thank you I will look for it ... but can I use that in arduino?

Comment: Yes you can. These are just commands issued over UART. You might only get into problems, if you try to buffer the full image in the Arduino. But as I wrote, you can pass the packages through, directly to the other module, so that you only have about 2 packets at the same time in the Arduino

Comment: thankyou!!! can you send me a link or guide on where should I start working plss

Comment: Start with the library from Adafruit, that you are already using. Try to understand, what the code does. Then you can use the manual, that I linked, and try to trigger the download/upload commands. If that works, you can extent the library for your use. There is no tutorial for doing that, so you need to dig into that topic yourself.