# How to extract fingerprint template from Arduino Fingerprint Sensor

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card

How to extract fingerprint template from Arduino Fingerprint Sensor and store it to SD card module using adafruit library and then search/import it from SD card module when tapping the fingerprint?

Can anyone give me hope to this project I am starting to feel stressed and depressed.

I'm using Arduino R307 and AS601 fingerprint modules.

here is the code:

```cpp
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <SD.h>
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    #include <Adafruit_Fingerprint.h>
    
    SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);
    
    
    
    Adafruit_Fingerprint finger = Adafruit_Fingerprint(&mySerial);
    
    uint8_t id;
    String userName;
    uint8_t isProfessor;
    char *myFileName = "acct.txt";
    File myFile;
    
    
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      while (!Serial);  // For Yun/Leo/Micro/Zero/...
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("\n\nAdafruit Fingerprint sensor enrollment");
    
      Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
      if (!SD.begin(4)) {
        Serial.print("initialization failed!");
        while (1);
      }
      Serial.print("initialization done.");
    
    
      // set the data rate for the sensor serial port
      finger.begin(57600);
    
      if (finger.verifyPassword()) {
        Serial.println("Found fingerprint sensor!");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Did not find fingerprint sensor :(");
        while (1) {
          delay(1);
        }
      }
    }
    
    uint8_t readnumber(void) {
      uint8_t num = 0;
    
      while (num == 0) {
        while (! Serial.available());
        num = Serial.parseInt();
      }
      return num;
    }
    
    void loop()                     // run over and over again
    {
      Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
      Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger as...");
      id = readnumber();
      if (id == 0) {// ID #0 not allowed, try again!
        return;
      }
      Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
      Serial.println(id);
    
      while (!getFingerprintEnroll() );
    }
    
    void writeReadSDCard(){
     
        delay(2000);
        // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
        // so you have to close this one before opening another.
        myFile = SD.open(myFileName, FILE_WRITE);
        // if the file opened okay, write to it:
        if (myFile) { //if myFile is open, you can write
          Serial.print("Writing to "); Serial.println(myFileName);
          //myFile.print(id); myFile.print(","); myFile.print(userName); myFile.print(","); myFile.println("Professor");
          myFile.print(id); myFile.print(","); myFile.println(userName);
          // close the file:
          myFile.close();
          Serial.println("done.");
        } else {
          // if the file didn't open, print an error:
          Serial.print("error opening when writing on "); Serial.println(myFileName);
        }
    
        delay(2000);
    
        // re-open the file for reading:
        myFile = SD.open(myFileName);
        if (myFile) {
          Serial.print("Reading SD Card file named "); Serial.println(myFileName);
    
          // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
          while (myFile.available()) {
            Serial.write(myFile.read());
          }
          // close the file:
          myFile.close();
          Serial.flush(); // wait for last transmitted data to be sent
     
        } else {
          // if the file didn't open, print an error:
          Serial.println("error opening for reading");   Serial.print(myFileName);
        }
    }
    
    
    
    uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll() {
    
      int p = -1;
      Serial.print("Waiting for valid finger to enroll as #"); Serial.println(id);
      while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
        p = finger.getImage();
        switch (p) {
          case FINGERPRINT_OK:
            Serial.println("Image taken");
            break;
          case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
            Serial.println(".");
            break;
          case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
            Serial.println("Communication error");
            break;
          case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
            Serial.println("Imaging error");
            break;
          default:
            Serial.println("Unknown error");
            break;
        }
      }
    
      // OK success!
    
      p = finger.image2Tz(1);
      switch (p) {
        case FINGERPRINT_OK:
          Serial.println("Image converted");
          break;
        case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
          Serial.println("Image too messy");
          return p;
        case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
          Serial.println("Communication error");
          return p;
        case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
          Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
          return p;
        case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
          Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
          return p;
        default:
          Serial.println("Unknown error");
          return p;
      }
    
      Serial.println("Remove finger");
      delay(2000);
      p = 0;
      while (p != FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER) {
        p = finger.getImage();
      }
      Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
      p = -1;
      Serial.println("Place same finger again");
      while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
        p = finger.getImage();
        switch (p) {
          case FINGERPRINT_OK:
            Serial.println("Image taken");
            break;
          case FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER:
            Serial.print(".");
            break;
          case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
            Serial.println("Communication error");
            break;
          case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEFAIL:
            Serial.println("Imaging error");
            break;
          default:
            Serial.println("Unknown error");
            break;
        }
      }
    
      // OK success!
    
      p = finger.image2Tz(2);
      switch (p) {
        case FINGERPRINT_OK:
          Serial.println("Image converted");
          break;
        case FINGERPRINT_IMAGEMESS:
          Serial.println("Image too messy");
          return p;
        case FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR:
          Serial.println("Communication error");
          return p;
        case FINGERPRINT_FEATUREFAIL:
          Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
          return p;
        case FINGERPRINT_INVALIDIMAGE:
          Serial.println("Could not find fingerprint features");
          return p;
        default:
          Serial.println("Unknown error");
          return p;
      }
    
      // OK converted!
      Serial.print("Creating model for #");  Serial.println(id);
    
      p = finger.createModel();
      if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
        Serial.println("Prints matched!");
      } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
        Serial.println("Communication error");
        return p;
      } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_ENROLLMISMATCH) {
        Serial.println("Fingerprints did not match");
        return p;
      } else {
        Serial.println("Unknown error");
        return p;
      }
    
    
      Serial.print("ID "); Serial.println(id);
      p = finger.storeModel(id);
      if (p == FINGERPRINT_OK) {
        Serial.println("Stored!");
    
        delay(10000);
       
          userName = Serial.readString();// read the incoming data as string
          Serial.println(userName);
    
          writeReadSDCard();
    
           
    
    
      } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_PACKETRECIEVEERR) {
        Serial.println("Communication error");
        return p;
      } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_BADLOCATION) {
        Serial.println("Could not store in that location");
        return p;
      } else if (p == FINGERPRINT_FLASHERR) {
        Serial.println("Error writing to flash");
        return p;
      } else {
        Serial.println("Unknown error");
        return p;
      }
    }
```

Here is the result:

[image]

I hope someone can answer my question.

Comment: Directly related to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/72887/2-fingerprint-scanner-using-1-arduino)

Comment: I don't think, that the library allows you to extract the template or model of a fingerprint. I even haven't seen such a function in the manual of the Adafruit Sensor. Only functions for getting the read image. So I guess you technically cannot get the template

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: What I wrote in my answer to your other question. Yes, that is no easy solution, but when you cannot find a library, that already implements the needed feature, you need to write that yourself. Or you need to rethink your project, so that you don't need this feature.